# Why not worked knockout foreach?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js

I do not, knockout foreach does not work.

View:

```
@using PerpetuumSoft.Knockout
@using WebIdea.Domain.Entities
@model WebIdea.Web.Models.KnockoutProductList
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    var ko = Html.CreateKnockoutContext();
}

<script src="/Scripts/knockout-2.1.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/perpetuum.knockout.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

@ko.Apply(Model)

@using (var items = ko.Foreach(m => m.Products))
{
<ul>
    <li>@items.Html.TextBox(x=>x.Url)</li>
</ul>
}
```

Model:

```
public class KnockoutProductList
{
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Html:

```
<script src="/Scripts/knockout-2.1.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/perpetuum.knockout.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

var viewModelJs = {"Products":[{"Id":"6d222412-87f1-402e-b705-27a89c1572dd","Name":"asdasd","Price":123123,"Url":"http://www.ya.ru/hh33.jpg"},{"Id":"d578f8f3-a6f1-415c-9fd9-7848709cf8e0","Name":"twertwert","Price":12.3,"Url":"http://jewelry.ecommanager.net/uploads/images/products/42eb3d1c-4e7f-41eb-8238-becaaaff100a-thumb.jpg"}]};

var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(viewModelJs); 

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
</script>

<!-- ko foreach: Products -->
        <ul>
        <li><input data-bind="value : Url" /></li>
       </ul>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages? What actually happens?

Comment: it happens, but should be 2 items displayed

Comment: Hi, what is `@ko.Apply(Model)`, thats not normal razor syntax, are you using a plugin of some kind?

Comment: no, I not use plugin only razor and knockout/js

Answer (score 0):

try to do this into your view:

```
<ul>
@using (var items = ko.Foreach(m => m.Products))
{
    <li>@items.Html.TextBox(x=>x.Url)</li>
}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should bind the value with "text":

```
<!-- ko foreach: Products -->
        <ul>
        <li><input data-bind="text: Url()" /></li>
       </ul>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Regards.